# Next.js - How to make sure <title> is set by the time the history change event fires?

Tags: next.js

In my Next.js app, I'm setting the `<title>` tag for individual pages using the recommended method:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

export default () => <>
    <Head><title>My page title</title></Head>
</>
```

Here's the problem: when the history change event fires, the value of `document.title` doesn't always match the current URL.

You can test it yourself:

```
Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => {
    if ('browser' in process) {
        console.log('--------');
        console.log(window.location.href);
        console.log(document.title);
    }
});
```

Navigating between pages, you should observe that URL & title are often mismatched. The value of URL is always right, but the value of title is all over the place. It can have:

- the right value
- the value it had on the previous page
- no value at all

This is an issue when using analytics, specifically GTM - Google Tag Manager, which uses the current URL & page title to uniquely identify visited pages.

I've had this issue with Next.js 7, and upgrading to 8 hasn't fixed it.

Do you know of any way to solve this problem? Maybe delaying the history change event until the first render of a component under `/pages/`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work-around by intercepting events sent to `window.dataLayer.push` and adding a one-second delay in case the event is `gtm.historyChange`.

Here's my `GtagScript` component that I'm adding to `<Head>` under `_document.js`:

```
export const GtagScript = () => {

    function intercept() {
        const scriptTag = document.querySelector('#gtm-js');
        if (scriptTag !== null)
            scriptTag.addEventListener('load', () => {
                window.dataLayer.pushOrig = window.dataLayer.push;

                window.dataLayer.push = (e) => {
                    if (e.event === 'gtm.historyChange') {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.dataLayer.pushOrig(e);
                            console.log(`URL: ${window.location.href} Title: ${document.title}`);
                        }, 1000);
                    } else {
                        window.dataLayer.pushOrig(e);
                    }
                };
            });
    }


    return <>
        <script
            id="gtm-js"
            async
            src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
        />
        <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}');
            ${intercept.toString()}
            intercept();`
            }}
        />
    </>
};
```

I'll wait a while to see if an official fix comes from the ZEIT team. My solution doesn't actually answer the question. It doesn't set `<title>`, it just defers the event, which isn't optimal.

Comment: Sometime, time load page will more than 1000ms. It isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small hack. `setTimeout(()=>{console.log(document.title)}, 0)`

Comment: The "hack" works (with a larger delay), but the problem is that we don't control how GTM detects the history change event. So even though our code get the right title, GTM gets the wrong value.

Comment: @Andrei check this https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4061#issuecomment-376319885

Comment: They're reporting that it worked in `5.1.0`. But the latest versions (`7`, `8`) seem to have a regression. Anyway, I solved it by intercepting events sent to `window.dataLayer.push` and adding a one-second delay in case the event is `gtm.historyChange`.

Comment: @Andrei post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use setInterval

```
const firstPageViewEvent = setInterval(() => {
  if (document.title) {
    // send pageview event
    clearInterval(firstPageViewEvent);
  }
}, 200);
```

Comment: This does the same as using `setTimeout` as suggested above, only more complicated